# KeyError: <greenlet.greenlet object at 0x10b5e37f0 (otid=0x10b605380) current active started main> while testing celery using pytest in flask

Tags: flask, pytest, celery

I am writing test cases using pytest for testing celery tasks and I am getting this error. I have configured the celery using the way given here https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/v4.3.0/userguide/testing.html#celery-worker-embed-live-worker.
I ran the debugger and found that this error occurs when task is trying to access database using db.session in export_rates task.

```
test_tasks.py::test_export_rates 
------------------------------ live log teardown -------------------------------
2022-09-28 11:56:09 ERROR Task app.tasks.export_rates[8d2557a2-173e-44f9-8e63-d70e25938ceb] raised unexpected: RuntimeError('No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1008, in __call__
    return self.registry[key]
KeyError: <greenlet.greenlet object at 0x10b5e37f0 (otid=0x10b605380) current active started main>
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 451, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/app/tasks.py", line 426, in export_rates
    vendor_rates = db.session.query(VendorRate).filter(VendorRate.vendor_id == id).all()
  File "<string>", line 2, in query
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 24, in _proxied
    return self.registry()
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1010, in __call__
    return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 4209, in __call__
    return self.class_(**local_kw)
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 174, in __init__
    self.app = app = db.get_app()
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1042, in get_app
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.


======================== 1 passed, 6 warnings in 0.14s =========================

Process finished with exit code 0
PASSED                                  [100%]2022-09-28 11:56:09 - ERROR - celery.app.trace:265 - _log_error - Task app.tasks.export_rates[8d2557a2-173e-44f9-8e63-d70e25938ceb] raised unexpected: RuntimeError('No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1008, in __call__
    return self.registry[key]
KeyError: <greenlet.greenlet object at 0x10b5e37f0 (otid=0x10b605380) current active started main>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 451, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/app/tasks.py", line 426, in export_rates
    vendor_rates = db.session.query(VendorRate).filter(VendorRate.vendor_id == id).all()
  File "<string>", line 2, in query
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 24, in _proxied
    return self.registry()
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1010, in __call__
    return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 4209, in __call__
    return self.class_(**local_kw)
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 174, in __init__
    self.app = app = db.get_app()
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1042, in get_app
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.
2022-09-28 11:56:09 - ERROR - celery.app.trace:265 - Task app.tasks.export_rates[8d2557a2-173e-44f9-8e63-d70e25938ceb] raised unexpected: RuntimeError('No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1008, in __call__
    return self.registry[key]
KeyError: <greenlet.greenlet object at 0x10b5e37f0 (otid=0x10b605380) current active started main>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 451, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/app/tasks.py", line 426, in export_rates
    vendor_rates = db.session.query(VendorRate).filter(VendorRate.vendor_id == id).all()
  File "<string>", line 2, in query
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 24, in _proxied
    return self.registry()
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1010, in __call__
    return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 4209, in __call__
    return self.class_(**local_kw)
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 174, in __init__
    self.app = app = db.get_app()
  File "/Users/walk_comp_017/Desktop/voice/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1042, in get_app
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.
```

I have configured the celery in the conftest file this way.

```
@pytest.fixture
def test_app():
    test_app = app
    test_app.config.update(
        TESTING=True,
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=os.getenv("DATABASE_URI"),
    )
    return test_app


@pytest.fixture
def client(test_app):
    yield test_app.test_client()

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def celery_config(test_app):
    return {
        'broker_url': "amqp://localhost",
        'result_backend': 'redis://',
    }


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def celery_worker_parameters(test_app):
    return {"without_heartbeat": False, "shutdown_timeout": 120}
```

Test case is written this way

```
def test_export_rates(celery_worker,celery_app,test_app):
    with test_app.app_context():
        export_rates.delay("vendor", 123, 'tessffvf', "abcd@gmail.com")
```

This is the code of export rate task.

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
    def export_rates(self, source, id, name, admin_mail_id):
        if source == "vendor":
            keys = ['country', 'network', 'prefix', 'billing', 'rate']
            file_name = f"vendors_rates_{datetime.datetime.now()}.csv"
            dialplan_type = "vendor"
    
            vendor_rates = db.session.query(VendorRate).filter(VendorRate.vendor_id == id).all()
```

code of create app

```
    def create_app() -> Flask:
        app = Flask(__name__, static_folder=None)
        app.config.from_object('config')
        # app.url_map.strict_slashes = False
    
        resources_init.configure_routes(api)
    
        configure_extensions(app)
        configure_error_handlers(app)
    
        return app
```

celery code

```
def make_celery(app, celery):
    # celery = Celery(app.import_name,    
    broker=config.CELERY_BROKER_URL)
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    celery.config_from_object(celery_config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
            logger.exception('Celery task failed', exc_info=exc)
            super(ContextTask, self).on_failure(exc, task_id,  
                 args,kwargs, einfo)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

def configure_extensions(app):
api.init_app(app)
db.init_app(app)
make_celery(app, celery)

Comment: Could you share an `app`, `db` definitions? Have you implemented `create_app`? If so share it please. It seems like the flask `app` was not created during tests at the first glance.

Comment: I am importing the app object from where I have defined the app.

Comment: i have shared the code of app and celery